# What the purpose of defining a code page for a firemonkey Mobile app?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In mobile project (Firemonkey, android/ios) is there any reason to set the code page of the app to be different from 0? as those projects work only with Unicode string and ansiString is even 'theoretically' not available

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Code page* parameter determines the code page of the source files and has no influence on the compiled program.

This is necessary when your source files are ANSI encoded and the used code page differs from your system default.

Comment: You mean the code page of all the .pas of the project ?

Comment: Yes. At least all with ANSI encoding (UTF-8 is recognized by a BOM). It is what the compiler help as well as the documentation says.